# If $Hash(x)$ is indistinguishable from $Hash(x,a)$, where $x$ is variable and $a$ is a given number?

Tags: hash

I try to use a sequence of games to prove a scheme is CCA secure. In the final two games, the ciphertexts are $(c_1^*, Hash(x)\oplus m_b, Hash(x,a))$ and $(c_1^*, random, Hash(x,a))$ respectively, where $c_1 ^*$ and $a$ can be viewed as given numbers, $x$ is a variable and $m_b$ is the challenge message.

The advantage of the adversary in the latter game obviously is 1/2, so if the two games are indistinguishable, then the advantage of the adversary in the original CCA game is also 1/2. Therefore, my question is if $(c_1^*, Hash(x)\oplus m_b, Hash(x,a))$ and $(c_1^*, random, Hash(x,a))$ are indistinguishable.

Or simpler, if $Hash(x)$ is indistinguishable from $Hash(x,a)$, where $x$ is a variable and $a$ is a given number? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it might be homework. Anyway, do you know any way a cryptographic hash function (that is pre-image and collision resistant) might help you distinguish

Comment: It seems what you need to prove is that $Hash(x) \oplus m_b$ (or really just $Hash(x)$) is indistinguishable from random given $c^*_1$ and $Hash(x,a)$. So it really depends on your assumptions on $Hash$ which are not stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks. If $Hash$ is (strong) collision resistant here, is it true that $Hash(x)$ is indistinguishable from $Hash(x,a)$ for a given $a$.

Comment: Like Guut Boy said it looks like you need to see whether  $Hash(x) \oplus m_b$ is distinguishable from random or maybe between $Hash(x) \oplus m_1$ and $Hash(x) \oplus m_2$ given  $c^*$ and $Hash(x,a)$ since it is IND- game

Comment: And to answer your question check difference between plain model and random oracle models of hash function. Also if the adversary can influence $a$, there is something you can do even with widely used hash functions based on MD constructions like SHA2 whose collision resistant property is intact (think about it) not just in theoretical constructions of hash functions in plain model.